# jQuery library optimized for Gecko engine

Tags: jquery, firefox, xul, gecko, zepto

Is there any jQuery library that's optimized/minimized only for use it with Gecko engine?

There's no need to support trident, webkit and so on if they're not gonna be used!

I wasn't successful in searching except zepto.js. Is it good enough and secure?

Comment: A library to do what?

Comment: Everything that jQuery can do, but without support for other engines in order to minimize size and increase speed..

Comment: @Swolfish, why would you want to use a library which is only supported by modern browsers? The static files are always zipped & cached on your system so you should not worry about the library size. Let me know exactly why do you want such a lib? I may be able to help you.

Comment: The reason is that I'm using desktop app (xul-->xulrunner), Mozilla's product, not widely used. It uses gecko engine and support for other engines is unnecessary. It's not problem with loading speed but speed of requests. I need lots of DOM manipulation and lots of css ad hoc changes, reflow is enough hard/frequent and app knows little freeze... I thought that script minimizing should give some improvement, but I still didn't do anything about this except minimazing DOM manipulation with clone and so on.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 2.0 removed support for IE and it shrunk the size down substantially (12%).

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

It also looks a bit faster..

http://jsperf.com/jquery-1-9-vs-2-0

Comment: Step forward for jQuery. :)

Comment: Yes and no, unfortunately a lot of us are forced to support IE due to the user base we serve..

Comment: It removed support for IE 6, 7 & 8. IE9 and higher are still supported with that version of JQuery.